# ERB conditionally include <% end %> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I wonder how to conditionally include an "end" tag

I have a lot of "form partials" like this one

*_form_part_x.html.erb* (But that doesn't adapt to what I want to do)

```
<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>
  <%= f.some_tag(...) %>
<% end %>
```

In many views, I just need to render one of these guys.

Now, the problem is that I want to have another big view for my Model, where I render all these partials (form_part_1, form_part_2; etc.). In my case, I am using bootstrap tabs, and every tab is a partial that, in turn, will call several partials `form_part_x` to generate specific fields.

BUT I don't want to have multiple form tags in my HTML, just one big form, so everything is saved at the same time. Therefore before my `render tabX`, I write the code to generate the HTML tag, and I close it after rendering all the tabs.

*simple_view.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'form_part_x' %>
```

*big_view.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(something) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'tab1', f:f %>
  <%= render 'tab2', f:f %>
    ...
  <%= render 'tab5', f:f %>
<% end %>
```

*_tab1.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'form_part_10', f:f %>
<%= render 'form_part_23', f:f %>
```

*_form_part_x.html.erb* (That could adapt to what I do If I knew how to add an <% end %> inside an <% if %> block

So basically, I thought I could tweak my partials to conditionally include the `<%= form_for(@model) do |f| %>` :

```
<%
# These lines help determine whether an HTML `form` tag should be generated or not
f ||= false
if not f then
  existing_form = false
else
  existing_form = true
%>

<% if not existing_form %>
  # If the partial is called without sending a local f, we want to create the HTML `form` tag
  <%= form_for(something) do |f| %>
<% end %>

  <%= f.text_field(:some_field) %>
  <p>Many more stuff</p>

<% if not existing_form %>
  # If the partial is called without sending a local f, we want to CLOSE the newly created HTML `form` tag
  <!-- I need to add an <% end %> here !
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd strongly consider going a different route; that would make reasoning about the page/form/partial more difficult.

Comment: @Surya Okay, so I have some tabs corresponding to the same model, but allowing to edit different properties. Before, I had one form for every different tab, but then I realised it was stupid, because only the params corresponding to the tab would be saved. (And basically, I have one partial for every tab, and each of them was calling other partials...)

Comment: ... And these "other partials", are also called by completely different views, some of tese views expect the partials to define the "form_for", other views already have the form_for defined, and pass the resulting f variable to the "other partials"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass to the **form_special** just paramters for a form construction:

**_form_special.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(something) do |f| %>
   <p>Many form-related stuff</p>
   <%- if case condition depending on the passed arguments as `params` %>
      <p>If case stuff: for example an additional `render_partial` </p>
   <%- end %>
<% end %>
```

Other view:

```
<%= render partial: 'form_special', params: parameters %>
```

For your exaplained specific case just avoid the case to render **_form_part_x.html.erb** outside the form, so it will be a:

```
<%= f.text_field(:some_field) %>
<p>Many more stuff</p>
```

And caller views:

```
<%= form_for(something) do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: form_part_x, f:f %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry Keyboard problems made me post before I was finished...

So you're saying I should actually rewrite the code in all my other files, so as to call `<%= form_for(something) do |f| %>` before rendrering the partial that contains the fields ?

Comment: This seems like the cleanest approach.

Comment: Otherwise, some friend suggested I could just do a `render_partial`, with a partial that only contains an `<%= end %>` tag...

Comment: Done. I hope it's better.